# Celery with memory backend hanging

Tags: python, flask, celery, pytest

I'm developing a testing suite for a flask app using celery for processing background tasks.

I am working on integration tests and have been trying to configure a embedded live worker as per the documentation (https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/testing.html)

conftest.py

```
@pytest.fixture(scope='session')
def celery_config():
    return {
        'broker_url': 'memory://localhost/',
        'result_backend': 'memory://localhost/',
    }

@pytest.fixture(scope='module')
def create_flask_app():
    #drop all records in testDatabase before strting new test module
    db = connect(host=os.environ["MONGODB_SETTINGS_TEST"], alias="testConnect")
    for collection in db["testDatabase"].list_collection_names():
        db["testDatabase"].drop_collection(collection)
    db.close()
    
    # Create a test client using the Flask application configured for testing
    flask_app = create_app()
    return flask_app

@pytest.fixture(scope='function')
def test_client(create_flask_app):
    """
    Establish a test client for use within each test module
    """
    with create_flask_app.test_client() as testing_client:
        with create_flask_app.app_context():
            yield testing_client 

@pytest.fixture(scope='function')
def celery_app(create_flask_app):
    from celery.contrib.testing import tasks
    from app import celery
    return celery
```

I'm trying to run the tests using local memory as the backend. Yet, the tasks hang and the test suite never finishes executing.

When I run the tests with a redis backend (and initialize redis in my development machine) everything works fine. But I'd like to not be dependent on redis when running the tests.

Am I doing something wrong with the setup? Does anyone have any idea on why the tasks are hanging?